# Json.Net - How to specify deserialized type in ambiguous JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can't seem to find a good answer so far, but I acknowledge maybe I'm just not smart enough to know the right keywords to search. So here goes.

Suppose I have a collection containing mixed object types:

```
var wishList = new List<WishListItem>
{
    new Car { Price = 78000, Make = "Tesla", Model = "S", Name = "Tesla Model S" },
    new Computer { Manufacturer = "Microsoft", Name = "Surface Pro 6", Price = 2000 },
    new PlatitudeIdea { Name = "World peace" }
};
```

As a collection built in memory, I can use casting to handle these objects according to their underlying types:

```
foreach (var wishListItem in wishList)
{
    if (wishListItem is PlatitudeIdea platitude)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{platitude.Name} is a hopeless dream");
    }
    else if (wishListItem is IPriceable priceThing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"At {priceThing.Price}, {priceThing.Name} is way out of my budget");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I want a {wishListItem.Name}");
    }
}
```

If I serialize it as a JSON array, everything looks fine...

```
[
    { "Price": 78000, "Make": "Tesla", "Model": "S", "Name": "Tesla Model S" },
    { "Manufacturer ": "Microsoft", "Name": "Surface Pro 6", "Price": 2000 },
    { "Name": "World peace" }
]
```

... but when I *parse* the JSON, the parser obviously can't tell exactly which type each element was originally, so it just tries to parse them as the lowest level type declared in the `List`'s generic parameter (`WishListItem`) as I would expect:

```
parsedWishList[0] is WishListitem // returns true :)
parsedWishList[0] is Car // returns false :(
```

This makes sense, and you could get this behavior any time the member being serialized is declared as a super type or interface. What I would love to be able to do is add a special property to my specific classes, indicating the type of the object being serialized:

```
public class Car : WishListItem, IPriceable 
{
    public override string @type => "Car";
}
```

Or better yet, as a type attribute:

```
[JsonSerializedType("Car")]
public class Car : WishListItem, IPriceable 
{
    // ...
}
```

This would then be output to the JSON whenever the type declaration is ambiguous...

```
[
    { "type": "Car", "Price": 78000, "Make": "Tesla", "Model": "S" },
    { "type": "Computer", "Manufacturer ": "Microsoft", "Name": "Surface Pro 6", "Price": 2000 },
    { "type": "Platitude", "Value": "World peace" }
]
```

... And the parser would deserialize that object as that type:

```
parsedWishList[0] is Car // returns true :)
```

The closest thing to an answer i was able to glean from Google was maybe to try playing with the `CustomCreationConverter` and see if that might help somehow. But I need a very generic answer I can write once and let it handle arbitrary types.

Any pointers?

Comment: Would it be unacceptable to you to have the type as a header? e.g. {
 "Car": {
  "Price": 78000,
  "Make": "Tesla",
  "Model": "S"
 }
}

Comment: Why would you need to have a mixed collection in the first place. From a coding logic perspective I get it, but not for serialization. How would the receiver know what the rules are? It would be better to group concrete types within their own lists or in the least case use some kind of wrapper with property names indicating the type as @PhilS suggests.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [JsonSubType](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes) library, as it seems close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Re @Silvermind and @PhilS:

So each `WishListItem` becomes a wrapper with a `Car` property to hold a car object, a `Computer` property to hold a computer object, a `Platitude` property to hold a platitude object, etc, right? That means that every time I add a new type, I'd have to modify the `WishListItem` and add a new if/else to the parser every time I add a new type. :( And no consume of my library could add their own types to store. Since my library will be the only thing reading or writing this json, I'm not worried about the receiver knowing the rules since I am the receiver.

Comment: @JonathonChase JsonSubType isn't _close_ to what I'm looking for. It's almost _exactly_ what I'm looking for :) You should add that as an answer

Comment: Have you tried using the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) setting?  This will cause Json.Net to write type information into the JSON so that it is deserialized back to its original type.

Comment: @BrianRogers, earlier I told Jonathan Chase that JsonSubType is almost exactly what I was looking for. But you have shown me the light. it looks like TypeNameHandling _is_ exactly what I was looking for. If only I could customize it to use an alias for the type name instead of the fully qualified type name. But still, that's awesome. Thanks! (This is a good answer, by the way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) setting. This setting will cause Json.Net to write type information into the JSON so that it is deserialized back to its original type.

If you need to customize the type names, you can use a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) class.

Here is a round-trip demo based on the `KnownTypesBinder` sample shown in the documentation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace SO54465235
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wishList = new List<WishListItem>
            {
                new Car { Price = 78000, Make = "Tesla", Model = "S", Name = "Tesla Model S" },
                new Computer { Manufacturer = "Microsoft", Name = "Surface Pro 6", Price = 2000 },
                new Platitude { Name = "World peace" }
            };

            KnownTypesBinder knownTypesBinder = new KnownTypesBinder
            {
                KnownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Car), typeof(Computer), typeof(Platitude) }
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wishList, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                SerializationBinder = knownTypesBinder
            });

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine();

            List<WishListItem> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WishListItem>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                SerializationBinder = knownTypesBinder
            });

            foreach (var wishListItem in wishList)
            {
                if (wishListItem is Platitude platitude)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{platitude.Name} is a hopeless dream");
                }
                else if (wishListItem is IPriceable priceThing)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"At {priceThing.Price}, {priceThing.Name} is way out of my budget");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"I want a {wishListItem.Name}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class KnownTypesBinder : ISerializationBinder
    {
        public IList<Type> KnownTypes { get; set; }

        public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            return KnownTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
        }

        public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
        {
            assemblyName = null;
            typeName = serializedType.Name;
        }
    }

    class WishListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    interface IPriceable
    {
        int Price { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Car : WishListItem, IPriceable
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }

    class Computer : WishListItem, IPriceable
    {
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }

    class Platitude : WishListItem
    {

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "$type": "Car",
    "Make": "Tesla",
    "Model": "S",
    "Price": 78000,
    "Name": "Tesla Model S"
  },
  {
    "$type": "Computer",
    "Manufacturer": "Microsoft",
    "Price": 2000,
    "Name": "Surface Pro 6"
  },
  {
    "$type": "Platitude",
    "Name": "World peace"
  }
]

At 78000, Tesla Model S is way out of my budget
At 2000, Surface Pro 6 is way out of my budget
World peace is a hopeless dream
```